# node red switch node does not have add rule button

Tags: node-red

I cant seem to figure out how to add rules to my switch node in node red. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Switch node config]

I have not tried many things other than watching some youtube videos, but I cant seem to find the rule button.

Comment: What version of Node-RED and What OS/Browser are you using. What happens if you clear the browser cache and reload the page (Also try a different browser)